# compare datetime64[ns] with timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

How can I compare `datetime64[ns]` with timestamp? Let's notice that `date_` is of type timestamp and `max_date` is of type timestamp.

**I did**

```
(df[(self.date_)] > (max_date))
```

Comment: When you say "timestamp", do you mean `float` (seconds from epoch) or `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`?

Comment: Hello @MaxPierini i mean pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```py
from datetime import datetime

(df[(self.date_)].astype(datetime) > max_date.to_datetime())
```

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce, let me do

```
date = pd.date_range(
    start=pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.Timedelta(days=10), 
    end=pd.to_datetime('now') + pd.Timedelta(days=10)
).to_numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date,
})

max_date = pd.Timestamp('now')
```

and check types

```
df.info()
```

that gives

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 21 entries, 0 to 20
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   date    21 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 296.0 bytes
```

and

```
type(max_date)
```

that gives

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Now, if we do

```
df[df.date > max_date]
```

we correctly get

```
                         date
11 2021-03-27 18:49:37.243613
12 2021-03-28 18:49:37.243613
13 2021-03-29 18:49:37.243613
14 2021-03-30 18:49:37.243613
15 2021-03-31 18:49:37.243613
16 2021-04-01 18:49:37.243613
17 2021-04-02 18:49:37.243613
18 2021-04-03 18:49:37.243613
19 2021-04-04 18:49:37.243613
20 2021-04-05 18:49:37.243613
```

Which error did you get instead?

Comment: Thank you! im gotting E   TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: Ok. So `max_date` is `Timestamp` from `pandas`. But `date_`? Did you `df['date_'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_)`?